# HTML produced with tufte.csl does not give sidenotes for footnotes and citations

Tags: html, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc, tufte

I have used pandoc before with the `tufte.css`  to produce a bibliography with references in sidenotes and a full bibliography at the end; it put footnotes from markdown into sidenotes as well.

I now use `citeproc` with pandoc 3.1.8 and  the bibliography notes are e.g. (Author-year) in the text. Footnotes inserted in markdown are also shown at bottom and not as sidenotes.

I think I still use the same `tufte.css` file as before. What did change? How to get the sidenotes back? Should I use `pandoc-sidenotes`, but perusing the code I doubt it would work with `citeproc` as it is produced now.

Alternatively, I could  edit the `csl` bibliography style; I seem to remember some hints to change `footnote` to `sidenote` in the bibliography style on stackoverflow, but cannot find them again.

The citations can be moved to the side by adding `.citation` to the `.sidenote` class in the `tufte.css` file. The same trick does not work for the footnotes produced by markdown.